# How can I get these span elements to expand to fill their full height?

Tags: html, css

#### CSS:

```
.events_holder {
    width:100%;
    background-color: #d9ceae;
}
    .events_holder .event_holder {
        width:100%;
        float: left;
        min-height: 20px;
    }
        .events_holder .event_holder .event_data {
            border: thin gray dotted;
            font-size: 80%;
            float:left;
            min-height:20px;
        }
        
        .events_holder .event_holder .event_date {
            width: 22%;
        }
        
        .events_holder .event_holder .event_title {
            width: 22%;
        }
        
        .events_holder .event_holder .event_venue {
            width: 15%;
        }
        
        .events_holder .event_holder .event_city {
            width: 27%;
        }
        
        .events_holder .event_holder .event_type{
            width: 10%;
        }
```

`.events_holder`, and `.event_holder` are both `div`'s, the rest are spans.
Every span also has the class `.event_data`.
The problem I am having now, is if one of the spans are taller than 20px, the other spans do not expand with them.

How can I get the height of the spans to be equal?

---

#### Markup:

```
<div class="events_holder"><div class="event_holder">
                <span class="event_date event_data faded">06/30/09<br>08:06 pm - 10:06 pm</span>

                <span class="event_title event_data">
                    event name<br>
                    <span class="small"> subtitle for the event </span>
                </span>
                <span class="event_venue event_data">
                    The NYC cafe
                </span>
                <span class="event_city event_data faded">

                    My first city
                </span>
                <span class="event_type event_data faded">
                    Events
                </span>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="event_holder">
                <span class="event_date event_data faded">06/19/09<br>08:06 pm - 10:06 pm</span>

                <span class="event_title event_data">
                    Test Event<br>
                    <span class="small">  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="event_venue event_data">
                    The NYC cafe
                </span>
                <span class="event_city event_data faded">

                    My first city
                </span>
                <span class="event_type event_data faded">
                    Events
                </span>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="event_holder">
                <span class="event_date event_data faded">06/19/09<br>08:06 pm - 10:06 pm</span>

                <span class="event_title event_data">
                    Copy of Test Event<br>
                    <span class="small">  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="event_venue event_data">
                    The NYC cafe
                </span>
                <span class="event_city event_data faded">

                    My first city
                </span>
                <span class="event_type event_data faded">
                    Events
                </span>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
      <div style="clear: both;">
```

Comment: This looks like a table, is there a reason why you don't want to use a table element?

Comment: Because there are an unending list of reasons why you should use tables. Number one being, they don't display until the entire table has been downloaded. This grouping could have images in it at some point.

Comment: OK, just asking. I believe if you declare 'table-layout:fixed' browsers will start to display the table contents before the entire table has downloaded (it's seems like you could do this given all your cells have defined widths). Otherwise you'll I think your only option is to use the 'table' and 'table-cell' 'display' declarations, which aren't supported in IE6/7.

Comment: Different browsers render tables in different ways. In `table-layout: auto` mode, some render incrementally (and adjust as they go along), some wait for all the data. None of them, as far as I know, fail to render incrementally when in `table-layout: fixed` mode. Use correct markup, otherwise you fall into the trap described at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html - 'CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with...'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a table. There will be less markup and it will automatically expand the rows to the largest height and keep your columns aligned.

```
table {
    width:100%;
    background-color: #d9ceae;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
    border: thin gray dotted;
    font-size: 80%;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>06/30/09<br>08:06 pm - 10:06 pm</td>
        <td>event name<br><span class="small"> subtitle for the event </span></td>
        <td>The NYC cafe</td>
        <td>My first city</td>
        <td>Events</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06/19/09<br>08:06 pm - 10:06 pm</td>
        <td>Test Event<br><span class="small">  </span></td>
        <td>The NYC cafe</td>
        <td>My first city</td>
        <td>Events</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06/19/09<br>08:06 pm - 10:06 pm</td>
        <td>Copy of Test Event</td>
        <td>The NYC cafe</td>
        <td>My first city</td>
        <td>Events</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Span is an inline element, so its naturally not going to grow to the size of its parent in the way that a block element such as a div does.

Having said that, there are a couple things I would try.

1. Make all the line height atributes of each span a fixed height - this is the only way that they will all be the same height.
2. try encasing each span column in a floating parent div, then clear the parent div.

   `<div id='container'>`
   `<div id='row' style="clear:both">`
     `<div id='column1' style='float:left'><span>text...</span></div>`
     `<div id='column2' style='float:left'><span>text...</span></div>`
   `</div>`
   `</div>`

Looks like previous answers have suggesting using a table.  I think a table may be better suited for what you are trying to do, but I also think its useful to know how to solve these problems using css because they do come up often.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are trying to do something that should be easy to do with a table .. 
and you can aplly all kinds of formatting to tables as well.

Maybe that's simpler to make it work ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried too much about compatibility with IE6 and older, you can just set the span element to display as an [inline block](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock).

```
.events_holder span { display: inline-block; }
```

That being said, I'd have to agree with what the others have been saying: this looks like tabular data, therefor you should use a table. There's nothing at all wrong with using tables where appropriate, and this certainly looks like an acceptable application.

Comment: that doesn't quite work. It causes all spans in their respective columns to be the same height, but if event_title could be taller than .event_city.

Answer (score 0):

display: block; but you should use a table!